# Create new application in django

Tags: django

When i create application inside the django project by using startapp, the application is created as read only. I cannot add any new files inside the application. What should I do for that? I am using Linux mint operating syst Please help.

Comment: use sudo django-admin startapp appname

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be creating app with super user privileges, and your editor won't have permission to read those files. Create new app without `sudo` like `python manage.py startapp appname` in non-superuser mode.

If this doesn't help, please provide the permission and owner of Django app folder